# Convert C++ string to long without out_of_range exception

Tags: c++, string

I need to convert a string with numbers into long variable to do some math operation.
For now i used `std::stol` to do it, but when i insert a value too big the method can't handle it and it stop with `argument out of range`.
So my question is: is there a way to convert string in long (or long long) type without go out of memory?

This is the code i used:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

std::string value = "95666426875";
long long converted_value = std::stoul(value.c_str());
//Some math calc here
std::cout << converted_value << std::endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What do you want to do when the input value is too large to fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `long` is 32-bit wide on your platform, so that `95666426875` is too big to fit into a 32-bit `long`.

Use `stoull` that parses into `unsigned long long`, instead of `stoul`. E.g:

```
auto converted_value = std::stoull(value);
```

(Note that you do not need to call `value.c_str()`).

Comment: In addition, there's potential to lose data converting from `unsigned long long` to `long long`, so either the variable should also be `unsigned long long` or `stoll` should be called. However, I feel like using `long long` might be a bandaid solution for the OP, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @chris Added an example with `auto`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The problem with your answer is that the example value in the code i posted is a user-input variable, so i can't know if the user will insert a bigger value..because i tried to insert something bigger and the program has stopped with the same error(even with `auto` instead of `unsigned long long`)

Comment: I just figure out that every software have a input limit(like system calculator), so i think it's better to not accept all values and put an error message for too big input..thanks for providing this solution @MaximEgorushkin !

Comment: @zDoes You can catch the exception and issue a more informative message to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringstream` as well :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main ()
{
  std::string value = "95666426875";

  //number which will contain the result
  unsigned long long Result;

  // stringstream used for the conversion initialized with the contents of value
  std::stringstream ss_value (value);

  //convert into the actual type here
  if (!(ss_value >> Result))
    {
      //if that fails set Result to 0
      Result = 0;
    }

  std::cout << Result;

  return 0;
}
```

run it yourself: [link](https://onlinegdb.com/SkS2Whcs-)